# `Write-Output` in `foreach` collection expression

Tags: powershell

I'm actually working my way through Bruce Payette's `Powershell in Action` and run to a code snippet I actually don't understand.

```
$characterData = @{                                                     
    'Linus' = @{ age = 8; human = $true}
    'Lucy' = @{ age = 8; human = $true}
    'Snoopy' = @{ age = 2; human = $true}
  }
  
  function Get-Character ($name = '*')
  {
    foreach ($entry in $characterData.GetEnumerator() | Write-Output)     
    {
      if ($entry.Key -like $name)
      {
          $properties = @{ 'Name' = $entry.Key } +                        
            $entry.Value
          New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $properties                 
       }
    }
  }
```

My problem is that I don't understand why `Write-Output` is used in `foreach ($entry in $characterData.GetEnumerator() | Write-Output)`? Can this syntax be interpreted as equivalent to `$characterData.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { ...`  ?

Thx

Comment: that `W-O` is entirely unneeded. you can remove the pipe and the `W-O` call entirely and the code still works. since the nunu-brain listed snoopy as human ... i presume the author of that code is mentally challenged. [*grin*]

Comment: Given this I assume is some kind of tutorial book (?), the Write-Output is probably just there to show you what's going on. I do similar things when debugging.

Comment: @Scepticalist The `Write-Output` doesn't show anything, it is totally superfluous.